# How to deploy/develop an WebService which in a 3 tier architecture?

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, 3-tier

**Background Info**

- WebService developed withc C# in .NET
- It needs to be published to the web
- It needs to have access to the database server.

The webservice is developed in a 3 layer architecture. I mean the webservice reference a DLL Project which process all the Business Logic and another DLL Project which handle all the database interaction.

**Problem**

My client have a 3 tier architecture. Therefore the Server which sees the database (APP SERVER) it is not published to the web, and the server which is published to the web (WEB SERVER) cannot see the database.

DB Server ----> App Server ----> Web Server

If I publish my WebService in the App Server I will not be able to access it from the web.

If I publish my WebService in the Web Server It will not be able to access the database.

**Question**

Which is the best approach for me to handle this:

1- Is there a way for me to put the Business Logic and Data Access DLLs in the App Server and publish my WebService in the Web Server?

2- or Do I need to install my WebService in the App Server, and Create and publish a "Dummy" WebService in the Web Server which consume the WebService in the app server and expose it to the web, en do NOTHING more.

3- Something else...

Answer (score 0):

You could consider setting up a proxy which simply forwards requests coming into the WebServer to the ApplicationServer. The WebServer is published to the internet but is in fact just a port-forwarding mechanism for forwarding HTTPS requests to your in-house server. You can place all the normal hardening on the Webserver to prevent attacks and a VPN from the WebServer to the ApplicationServer will mean the ApplicationServer does not need to be published to the web.